# Remove a 2nd Nic IP on a DC

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip, domain-controller, nic

In a windows 2003 DC (with DNS role) I need to remove a 2nd ip (added many years ago by precedent sysadmin and no one know why!) on a single NIC.
This because the domain have a new trust with an other domain and we have many connections issues with applications.

Someone Know if is needed a reboot for having changes to take effect?
The DNS will update the entry automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no reboot required to change or remove a second IP.

DNS won't 'update' automatically, though. It should eventually expire, but I'd recommend manually deleting the record. A reboot won't help with that, either.